# Blazor table component not updating dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I ran into an issue with server-side Blazor trying to create a custom table component. The data in the table rows updates and changes dynamically so that is not the issue but if I bind the header on a property, the header will take the previous value of that property.

From table.razor, I am setting up a simple dropdown `<select>` tag with default values. When that value is changed, it should update the value on the table header.

I have added a `<code>` tag and a classic HTML table as a test and they both reflect the new `<select>` value properly. Any idea why it's not the same for a custom component?

Table.razor

```
@page "/table"

@using BlazorApp1.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<select @bind="@SelectedListItem">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>

<code>@SelectedListItem</code>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@SelectedListItem</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <BlazorApp1.Components.DataTable Items=@forecasts TRowItem="WeatherForecast">
        <BlazorApp1.Components.Column CustomTitle="@SelectedListItem" TRowItem="WeatherForecast"></BlazorApp1.Components.Column>
    </BlazorApp1.Components.DataTable>
}

@code{
    public string SelectedListItem { get; set; }

    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

DataTable.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp1.Components
{
    public partial class DataTable<TRowItem> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public IList<TRowItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<TRowItem>();

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

        private IList<Column<TRowItem>> Columns { get; set; } = new List<Column<TRowItem>>();

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            if (Items == null) Items = new List<TRowItem>();
        }

        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            await UpdateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync()
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        public void Refresh()
        {
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                foreach (var column in Columns)
                {
                    column.StateChanged += ColumnStateChanged;
                }
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var column in Columns)
            {
                column.StateChanged -= ColumnStateChanged;
            }
            Items.Clear();
        }

        public void AddColumn(Column<TRowItem> column)
        {
            Columns.Add(column);

            StateHasChanged();
        }

        private void ColumnStateChanged(Object? sender, EventArgs args) => StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

DataTable.razor

```
@typeparam TRowItem

<h3>DataTable</h3>



<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach(var column in Columns)
                    {
                        <th nowrap>@column.CustomTitle</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach(var item in Items)
                {
                    foreach(var column in Columns)
                    {
                        <td></td>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>

            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

Column.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace BlazorApp1.Components
{
    public partial class Column<TRowItem> : ComponentBase
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        private DataTable<TRowItem>? DataTable { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public string? CustomTitle { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public Expression<Func<TRowItem, object>>? Property { get; set; }

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            if (DataTable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException($"A 'DataTableColumn' must be a child of a 'DataTable' component");

            DataTable.AddColumn(this);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public event EventHandler? StateChanged;

        private void RaiseStateChanged()
        {
            EventHandler? handler = StateChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Column.razor

```
@typeparam TRowItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea why it's not the same for a custom component?

Any change in your select causes a Blazor UI event in the page which triggers a re-render event.  The Renderer does this by triggering `SetParametersAsync` on the component The component updates its parameters, runs `OnParametersSet{Async}` and re-renders.

`DataTable` contains `Column` so it re-renders first.  At this point `CustomTitle` in `Column` hasn't run `SetParametersAsync`, so `DataTable` renders the current "old" value.  `Column` then re-renders setting `CustomTitle` to the new value.

Based on the code you've shown the answer is to render the label in the `Column` component.  But I'm guessing that's a bit more complex in reality, so that's probably not the answer.  You probably want it to show the title in the header section and the value in the row template.  If so I can point you to some code that shows how to do that.

The solution is not to do some more plumbing or put in some more `StateHasChanged`, but to rethink what your doing.  Get the data i.e. your table configuration into a data class/classes and cascade that down to your individual components.  Or use a DI service to hold the data and drive the component updates by events.

Comment: Can you provide some example for the last paragraph? I would like the table to be a reusable component that is self-contained and able to manage that kind of logic on its own.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Database/tree/master/Blazr.UI.Bootstrap/Components/Lists  It doesn't do configurable columns but does show various other techniques for building a table.

Comment: Can confirm that this is the way to go.